# Make the facebox popuped page draggable, possible?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, draggable, facebox

Im using the facebox method to popup a page. however is there a way to make this facebox draggable?.. I saw many articles about draggable contents, but how can i achieve it using facebox ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox().click(function () {
                lastVisited = this.href;
            });
        });
```

this is my code, is there a property to make it draggable? i tried draggable:true

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oke here is the solution:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function(){ 
            $('#facebox').draggable(); 
        }) 
    </script>
```

NB: dont forget the jquery UI js file

Answer (score 0):

Adding jQuery UI and its draggable class will do the trick.

Comment: yeah but i dont know how to use it with facebox.

Comment: Try adding the draggable class to your div. Make sure u include, jQuery, jQueryUI, draggable pligun.